# Use await in python REPL directly

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am wondering if there is a way to call `async` functions with `await` directly from python REPL ?

So having following code as example:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def somefunc():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        host_url = 'https://somehost'
        async with session.get(host_url) as resp:
            response = await resp.json()
        return response
```

What I am looking for is an easy way to debug similar functions, basically I'd like to

```py
>>> result = await somefunc()
```

I am aware that this can be done with

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(somefunc())
```

But using this approach I would need to either alter the body of somefunc to log the result of the response or use additional async function such as below to print the result

```py
async def result_print():
    result = await somefunc()
    print(result)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(result_print())
```

Summarising the things above, I am looking for a more convenient way to await async functions in the python REPL, maybe a custom REPL implementation that allows

```py
>>> result = await somefunc()
```

Or possible there's a way to do that in python default repl that I am not aware of ?

Comment: I found out that there's a way to do that with IPython
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html, but I'm still wondering if there's a better way of handling this, ideally default python repl

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The behavior you want is available if you launch the REPL using

```
python -m asyncio
```

Comment: I have also noticed this only works for python 3.8 or higher

Comment: This was implemented for https://bugs.python.org/issue37028 and is still waiting for somebody to copy over the code for tab completion and history file.  The person who implemented it seemed to prefer to direct people to ipython, which already does this, and then somebody unfortunately closed the issue even though the implementation was just an example.  There might be a newer discussion somewhere.

Comment: One problem with this solution is `-m` is an "interface option" which results in PYTHONSTARTUP variable getting ignored.  Is there a way to have my async shell and pythonrc at the same time?

Comment: I'd rather have the convenience of the normal ipython shell + pythonrc and have to use asyncio.run() instead of await vs using the async REPL.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand how you couldn't get the response, it appears to be returned from `loop.run_until_complete(somefunc())`

I ran that code in the question with only one change to the url, using `host_url = 'https://httpbin.org/json'`

```
>>> response = loop.run_until_complete(mytest.somefunc())
>>> response
{'slideshow': {'author': 'Yours Truly', 'date': 'date of publication', 'slides': [{'title': 'Wake up to WonderWidgets!', 'type': 'all'}, {'items': ['Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great', 'Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets'], 'title': 'Overview', 'type': 'all'}], 'title': 'Sample Slide Show'}}
>>>
```

Comment: question was how to get this done without creating a loop instance and running it with `run_until_complete` or similar

Comment: right, though maybe it's a little misleading to say you have to modify the code to get a similar effect to using await keyword in the repl